# ideal $\check I(\lambda)$: the definition is missing

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, ideals, cardinals

[Here](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/898/) on the page 15 in the definition 1.14 is $\check I[\lambda]$ defined but $\check I(\lambda)$ ideal not.
Does someone know what is this round brackets notation?

**EDIT** BTW, on the page 9 [there](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/898/)
in the same paper,
0.5(3) in the proof of claim 0.14(1) refers to unknown reference. What is the correct place to look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like $\check I(\lambda)$ is simply a typo of $\check I[\lambda]$, and the complicated definition of "witnesses for $S\in \check I[\lambda]$" was just deferred momentarily from item 1) to item 2) in the enumerated list.